# Can't Delete Files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Using a Mac.

I've created a blog for a demo learning Ruby on Rails. I'm trying to delete the files to the blog I created but there are some files remaining that won't delete.

I keep getting an error saying that "development.sqlite3" is in use. I don't what is using this file, how to find it, and how to quit it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How are you running your blog? Passenger? `rails server`? Have you tried restarting your computer?

Comment: How are you trying to delete the files? (The `rm(1)` program probably doesn't care about the file being "in use", but I can't state that specifically.) The `fuser(1)` utility will help you find whichever process _is_ using the file, in any event. (`lsof(1)` for people on other platforms who are trying to track down this same problem...)

Comment: No I haven't tried by restarting my computer. 

I think I have a server running from one of the demos I was doing and I don't know how to end it.

Comment: I'm trying to delete them by dragging them to the trash bin and then emptying it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've probably got a `ruby` process running somewhere. Launch [Activity Monitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_Monitor), find a `ruby` process, and kill it. (Presumably this is the only Ruby program you have running on your machine, but double check.)

Comment: Yep. That was it. How can I end ruby processes from terminal without having to use activity monitor every time?

My computer started to heat up to 80 degrees for no reason one day until I realized I was running like 5 instances of ruby.

Comment: Try `killall ruby` from a Terminal prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Restart your mac and try it again

Comment: Sure, restarting would probably work, but that's a pretty drastic way to solve the problem. Suppose you wanted to restart the server every time you changed the code? Rebooting each time would be unacceptable.

Comment: I think he wasnt working on a server, more on a development machine. And its the most easiest way to cope with it.

Comment: I meant "server" as software, not server as hardware. Even development machines need to run server software.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the computer works most of the times. If it doesn't you can try to hold "alt" key when you empty the trash can if the files are already there.

Alternatively you can use the terminal

```
sudo rm -rf yourFileName
```

Comment: This is not a permissions problem, so using `sudo` won't help. It's not recommended to use `sudo` as just a "bigger hammer" when something doesn't work.